# Momentary click in android

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

i have an adapter with RecyclerView that show some items and everything is ok for showing , in my issue i want click Momentary via OnTouch Method in android

```
            holder.objectImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                        Log.e("test", "ACTION_DOWN");

                        // Do what you want
                        return true;
                    }

                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){


                        Log.e("test", "ACTION_UP");


                        // Do what you want
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

in this code **ACTION_DOWN** is working perfect every time but **ACTION_UP** not working every time

How i can handle this problem ?

Comment: what do you mean by momentary click?

Comment: momentary is doing something every time when Down and Up

Answer (score 0):

You can try like the following.

```
holder.objectImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

             Log.e("test", "ACTION_DOWN");

             // Do what you want
             // return true; remove this line
          }

          else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

             Log.e("test", "ACTION_UP");

             // Do what you want
             // return true; remove this line
         }
         return true; // need to return true.
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried with your code but not works every times like my code

Comment: which part must be define status  in Adapter ?

Comment: I tried with your code but doesn't changed problem. some times works everything and some times just ACTION_DOWN work

Comment: I don't know what happens to you. by the way, I have updated my answer again. now you can remove all `status` and `return` statement except bottom`return` and change bottom `return`  `true`. Hope it works properly.

Comment: Yes i know why this code not work every times , i did all changes but some times Action_Up dosen't run

Answer (score 0):

Try like this below code :

```
 holder.objectImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                     Log.i("TAG", "touched down");
                   break;
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                     Log.i("TAG", "moving: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");                
                   break;
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                     Log.i("TAG", "touched up");
                   break;
             }

             return true;
            }
        });
```